# Override Environment Variables on DockerStartContainer

Tags: gradle, docker-container

I'm using the following plugin https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin and I'm trying to figure out how to pass environmental variables to the docker container in the task type DockerStartContainer.

When I runn the following I get the error:

> Could not set unknown property 'VAR1' for task
>   ':createDockerContainer' of type
>   com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.container.DockerCreateContainer.

```groovy
task buildDockerImage(type: DockerBuildImage) {
  dependsOn buildDockerAssets
  inputDir = buildDockerfile.destFile.parentFile
  tags = [ "${dockerRepo}:${project.findProperty('dockerTag') ?: 'latest'}".toString() ]
}

task createDockerContainer(type: DockerCreateContainer) {
  dependsOn buildDockerImage
  targetImageId { buildDockerImage.getImageId() }
  VAR1 = project.findProperty('VAR1') ?: 'va1'
  VAR2 = project.findProperty('VAR2') ?: 'val2'
}
```

I'm guessing I need to do something like `env = ["var1=val1", "var2=val2"]` but I'm just not sure. Anyone know the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`VAR1` and `VAR2` do not exist as properties on the `DockerCreateContainer` type. Looking at the [source code, there is an `env` property](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin/blob/967089e83d33a3ed54f783ce8f0740cc76db6c83/src/main/groovy/com/bmuschko/gradle/docker/tasks/container/DockerCreateContainer.groovy#L90-L92) that you can modify.

Example:

```groovy
task createDockerContainer(type: DockerCreateContainer) {
  dependsOn buildDockerImage
  targetImageId { buildDockerImage.getImageId() }
  env = [
      "VAR1=${project.findProperty('VAR1') ?: 'va1'}",
      "VAR2=${project.findProperty('VAR2') ?: 'val2'}"
  ]
}
```

---

**2018/07/09 EDIT**: Recent releases of the plugin ([see the release notes](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin/blob/8c975e2ebb6c2a76238124540ede632fcc4e9a08/RELEASE_NOTES.md#version-340-july-1-2018)) have deprecated the `env` property in favor of using a new property named `envVars` that is a `Map<?, ?>`. The release notes states that it was released in Version 3.4.0.

An example of how to configure the task now can be seen in the [test code](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin/blob/c80383bdf81a57b44523bb8a7a89fb72dcaa54f0/src/functTest/groovy/com/bmuschko/gradle/docker/DockerCreateContainerFunctionalTest.groovy#L85-L99) (included below):

```groovy
task createContainer(type: DockerCreateContainer) {
  dependsOn pullImage
  targetImageId { pullImage.getImageId() }
  cmd = ['env']

  // deprecated, use the below examples
  env = ['HELLO=WORLD']

  // add by appending new map to current map
  envVars << ['one' : 'two', 'three' : 'four']

  // add by calling helper method N number of times
  withEnvVar('five', 'six')
  withEnvVar('seven', 'eight')
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The code says:

// use `envVars` instead
    @Deprecated
    @Input
    @Optional
    String[] env

    @Input
    @Optional
    final Map<?, ?> envVars = [:]

env is deprecated, and I'm trying to set envVars but doesn't work

Comment: @Perimosh thanks for pointing that out. It looks like it has changed in recent versions, and I have edited my question to call that out.

Comment: Oh actually I did realize about something else, but didn't update this post. If you open the code for version 3.2.4, which is the latest, the code only shows "env" and doesn't show "envVars". I think they are over some ongoing working on master branch, but the branch for 3.2.4 is correct. I will vote up your answer because it worked for me:

env = ["var1=value1", "var2=value2"]